# Why did <entityFramework> and <configSections> tags appear in my web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config

Why did this code appear in my web.config file? It was not there when I created my ADO.NET Entity Data Model so what event triggered the generation of this code?

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework"
      type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
      requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>

  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

Comment: Did you add the EF nuget package?

Comment: Yes, When I created the ADO.NET Entity Data Model it automatically downloaded and installed the EntityFramework via NuGet @Will

Comment: That's it then.

Comment: Yeah I just read that on Microsofts EntityFramework guide here    
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file  Weird thing is that I had another project that I installed EF6 on and it did not put those tags in the web.config file. That's Why I was confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework packages install automatically in several instances. For example, when you create a project using ready templates such as ASP.Net MVC project with Individual authentication enabled. Because in that case the application will be tied up with EF to handle all authentication related DB interactions. 
Secondly, If you add a Model class and a controller with a scaffolding to generate views using Entity Framework ("MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework"). In this case, if the entity framework is not already configured the scaffolding mechanism does that job. As a result we see all EF related configurations in web.config and DLL references in the project. This leads to little bit of confution when we start working on these new project templates in visual studio.